# Open perf.data in Kcachegrind

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, valgrind, perf

I read somewhere that it is possible to convert `perf.data` (output from linux `perf record` profiling tool) to a format that kcachegrind can parse/plot, however I didn't find an application capable of doing this convertion and neither does kcachegrind opens `perf.data`.

Is this possible: use kcachegrind to see perf output? Which tool can I use?

Answer (score 13):

There are two approaches for conversion of perf data to callgrind format, but its unclear which of them is more mature.
The one with more current commits called perfgrind can be found at https://github.com/ostash/perfgrind
However, it is stated to lack callgraph support, and commits came to a halt after announcement of a patch for the 2nd tool on the kernel mailing list, see lkml.org/lkml/2013/3/27/535.

The 2nd tool https://github.com/vitillo/perf approaches direct integration into the perf command, but has not yet seen an official release.
At least the perf 3.10.0 I tried does not support the proposed 'perf convert' syntax.

Comment: It looks like there is now a third tool: https://github.com/milianw/linux/blob/milian/perf/tools/perf/scripts/python/callgrind.py

It is by the author of https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot